# Finding if two triangle are congruent

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop

The problem goes like this:

> > Write a program that reads the three angles and sides of two triangles and print if they are         congruent or not. We do not how many times the user wants to do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    float l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6;
    float a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6;
    char ans;
    int d=1;

    while(d<=2)
    {            
        printf("\nIntroduce the sides of triangle %d:",d);
        scanf("%f %f %f",&l1,&l2,&l3);
        printf("Introduce the angles of triangle %d:",d);
        scanf("%f %f %f",&a1,&a2,&a3);
        {
        if(l1==l4 &&l2==l5 && l3==l6 && a1==a4 && a2==a5 && a3==a6)
             printf("\n\tCongruent");
        else
             printf("\n\tNot congruent");
        }
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

That's my code but there is a problem in the beggining, because i soon as it ends the angles prompt, the program just finishes and says they are not congruent, without ever asking for triangle number 2, therefore i havent done the "asking is the user wants to do other triangles thing". I know that my code is somewhat wrong, but i dont get where.

All help is appreciatead!

Comment: Comparing equality in floating point will not end well!

Comment: A debugger will help you step through the code. It's not really magic that a program works or doesn't.  Visual Studio has a great debugger. Just hit F10 one line at a time.

Comment: @bathsheba is right in general, comparing floating point numbers using `==` is not recommended because of truncation and round-off errors. Most reasonable inputs will work in this case though, as long as you don't do any arithmetic with the floats.

Comment: There's no assignment of l4, l5 and l6. Also there is no need to check all sides and triangle, just 3 equal sides or equal side-angle-side or angle-side-angle is enough

Comment: If you think any of the answer given below solves your problem, please consider to accept it so that it can float up on the top and other readers can be benefited.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your loop is incomplete.  Instead of `while(d<=2)`, I recommend `for (int d = 1; d <= 2; ++d)`.

Is it a requirement that the user enter the vertices of both triangles in the same sequence?  If not, then you would need to check WHICH angles match, then check the corresponding sides.  Also, is in necessary to validate that the given angles and sides form a valid triangle? This could potentially become a very complicated problem.

Comment: For congurency 1 of SSS, SAS, ASA, RHS or AAS is enough. Now because OP reads all 3 sides, one can use SSS axiom to compare only sides and ignore angles completely. This can not be categorized as complicated problem, rather it is a good way to test your skills to write loop and condition blocks effectively.

Comment: So it's better for me to use only one? I was thinking of using both SSS and SAS , just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

- You are comparing the sides before you read the data from both triangles. The comparison must be outside the while.
- You need to increment d somewhere (anywhere) inside the loop.
- You dont need those { } closing the if-else.
- You are not checking if the values are acceptable, so let's suppose whoever use this program will only provide correct value, so...
- The easiest way to check for congruency would be to check if all the sides on the first triangle has a correspondent side on the second triangle.

  The way to do the comparison I'll leave to you as a challenge... You can start as:

  ```
  if(l1 == l4 && l2 == l5 && l3 == l6) ...
  ```

  Think how you would solve that in a papper or something, once you have an idea on how to solve, try and implement it. =)

Answer (score -1):

I went and changed and added some things, and now it looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
float l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6;
float a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6;
char resp;
printf("\n\t Triangles");
printf("\nBegin?");
 while(resp=getchar()=='y')
    {
      fflush(stdin);
      printf("\nIntroduce the sides of the first triangle:");
      scanf("%f %f %f",&l1,&l2,&l3);
      printf("Introduce the angles of first triangle:");
      scanf("%f %f %f",&a1,&a2,&a3);
      printf("\nIntroduce the sides of the second triangle:");
      scanf("%f %f %f",&l4,&l5,&l6);
      printf("Introduce the angles of the second triangle:");
      scanf("%f %f %f",&a4,&a5,&a6);
      fflush(stdin);
            if((l1==l4|| l1==l5 ||l1==l6) && (l2==l4 ||l2==l5 || l2==l6) && (l3==l4 || l3==l5 || l3==l6))
                 printf("\n\tCongruent");
            else
              printf("\n\tNot congruent");

             printf("\nMore triangles?:");
    }
     getch();
     return 0;
 }
```

It runs pretty good , does everything fine but i was wondering is there any way to do the problem without asking for `printf("\nBegin?");`, or asking for it is the only way to do it?

If there is another way , do that means that i will have to change my`while(resp=getchar()=='y')`?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` causes undefined behaviour, don't do it

Comment: Also not sure what `resp` is for; and your test condition is logically incorrect (e.g. it will report `(3,3,4)` congruent to `(3,4,5)`), and you should take some action if `scanf` did not successfully complete.

Comment: `resp` would be like saying answer, just that i put in another language. So also i should eliminate both `fflush(stdin)`? Also, how should i fix the condition?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say about `resp` . The value of `resp` is never used so why is it in the program?   And yes, do not do `fflush(stdin);`.

Comment: My teacher has told us to use `resp` when we want to get an answer to a prompt.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood what you were told; all this does is set `resp` to either `0` or `1` and then never use it. It would work the same to write `while (getchar() == 'y')`.

Comment: Yeah, i just tried the `while(getchar()=='y'`and it was the same.But with this teacher i prefer to do it her way of fear of she putting it wrong. But thanks for the help. I also went and fixed the test condition, I wouldn't have noticed if you hadn't put the example! So thanks a lot.

Comment: Your program runs wrong, you need to check all 6 permutations, not checking if any pair of sides is equal. And why are you insisting on input all 3 sides and 3 angles when that's not necessary. You're not checking the angles too.

Comment: I have to input all 3 sides and angles because the problem tells me to do so, and also checking the permutations is kinda long, doing SSS,SAS,ASA,AAS is kinda long.So the best option is to check for all the congruency theorems instead of one?

Comment: Yes there is a better way. You can replace `while(){...}` with `do {...} while()`. Also carefully read the comments from @MattMcNabb.

Comment: Can't use`do {...}while{}` because the teacher hasn't explained that function yet, so if i put it I'll most likely get the problem wrong in her eyes.

Comment: OK then, replace `char resp; while(resp=getchar()=='y') {...}` with `char resp = 'y'; while(resp=='y') {...; resp=getchar(); }`